# No .fonts folder in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts

In previous LTS version of Ubuntu, there was a .fonts folder in /home that to install fonts it was enough to copy fonts there. I'm new to 16.04 and there isn't such folder. Is it possible to create that folder or something else should be done to install fonts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just create a `.fonts` folder in your home directory.

```
$ mkdir .fonts
```

And copy the fonts into that directory. Then run font cache command.

```
$ fc-cache -f -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the fonts in the standard locations (you'll get specific folders there) : `/usr/share/fonts`,`/usr/local/share/fonts`, and `~/.fonts`.
Or you can head over to `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` to define the locations or to know where the locations are.